Compatibility of DCM/CCl3 with sodium hydride
In our undergraduate studies we were told that chlorinated solvents should not get in contact with alkaline elements like sodium, potassium etc., due to the violent reaction that will form the corresponding salts. A couple of years later I recently saw on YouTube content that implies that the reaction between sodium and DCM in reality will not occur or only in a slow fashion, while potassium will react more readily. Is there reliable data on this?
Exothermic runaway was discussed in the literature for DMSO and DMF with sodium hydride, however I have also already used sodium hydride in combination with DMF, because using solely THF will not bring all the necessary reactants into solution in that specific case.
Can chlorinated solvents under specific conditions be used with sodium hydride? Especially DCM and chloroform? How readily are carbanions formed, that may have a negative influence on the reaction and produce unwanted alkylation products?

Stay clear of active metals and halogenated solvents. DMSO anion is prepared with NaH at 65 oC. DMF and NaH are compatible at room temperature. I've used them for alkylations.

Neither chloroform nor DCM can be used safely with NaH.
Chloroform reacts with hydroxide or t-butoxide to form dichlorocarbene, so a much stronger base such as sodium hydride is clearly incompatible.
Dichloromethane similarly reacts with strong base to produce chlorocarbene which has been used to generate chlorocyclopropanes from alkenes [1, 2].
References

Closs, G. L.; Closs, L. E. Syntheses of Chlorocyclopropanes from Methylene Chloride and Olefins. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1959, 81 (18), 4996–4997. DOI: 10.1021/ja01527a057.
Closs, G. L.; Closs, L. E. Carbenes from Alkyl Halides and Organolithium Compounds. I. Synthesis of Chlorocyclopropanes1. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1960, 82 (21), 5723–5728. DOI: 10.1021/ja01506a041.


I am wondering however, if no alkenes are present to which the carbanions can add to. What will happen to these species?

As a highly reactive species they will find something to react with. Carbene C-H  insertion is always a possibility. In the presence of metal catalyst (notably Cu & Rh) it can be selective. Without metal catalysis you will get a mixture of products.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbene_C%E2%88%92H_insertion

Granted. However, what when no CH is present? Just the solvent and NaH in an Gedankenexperiment?  Is some recombination mechanism possible like it is known from radicals as a termination step?

Depends on what your solvent is

For the sake of the argument: DCM or Chloroform. Carbene would be formed, but how would they vanish if they are stirred without substrate?

My best guess is polychloroalkanes formed by carbene insertion to the C-H bonds of chloroform and dichloromethane
